# Calling static method in main part

Tags: java

How can I call a method in the main method ?

```
public class Sum extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        int[][] array = {{32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6},
                        {4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34},
                        {64235, 23, 522, 124, 42}};
    }

    public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
             sum += array[row][col];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I used this option

```
public void run() {
    int[][] array = {{32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6},
                    {4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34},
                    {64235, 23, 522, 124, 42}};
    sumRow(); // and this way System.out.println(sumRow);
    
}
```

Expected result:

```
144
889
64946⏎
```

Actual result:

```
You forgot to print something.
```

Comment: As an aside, `sumRow` prints nothing by itself. You have to [print the array it returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array).

Comment: `sumRow(array)`?!

Comment: a function is like a machine where you can put something in and get something out. you have to give the arrray into it and the parameter row is not needed

Comment: Please read the help pages on how to format your question correctly. You're supposed to print 3 different sums, one on each line, but because of your lack of formatting your question appears to show a number on just one line.

Comment: posted "option" should not compile - missing arguments to `sumRow` call

Comment: You need to `System.out.println(sumrow(array, row));` for all rows.

Comment: To get proper answer please first describe what specific result you expect. Also note that `print` lets us *display* value, like on console. The `return` lets us *give* value back to other part of a program which asked for it. BTW `sumRow` is declared to require array and row number but you are not providing it in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row)
```

this requires a matrix `int[][] array` and an integer `int row` as inputs.
then it outputs an integer `static int` as output.
Therefore when you call the function you must write it like so:

```
sumrow(array, row);
```

And print it out like so:

```
System.out.println(sumrow(array, row));
```

As pointed out by @k314159.
To get the output of all three arrays inside the matrix you would have to:

```
System.out.println(sumrow(array, 0));
System.out.println(sumrow(array, 1));
System.out.println(sumrow(array, 2));
```

And this should output the sum of all three arrays in the matrix.
Also I would like to point out that `int[][]` is a matrix and not an array, so it would be more "correct" to declare it like so:

```
public class Sum extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        int[][] matrix = {{32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6},
                        {4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34},
                        {64235, 23, 522, 124, 42}};
    }

    public static int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
             sum += matrix[row][col];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also be good to use a loop instead of hard-coding the rows as `0`, `1` and `2`, but perhaps better to leave that as a learning exercise for the OP.